# Parse datetime string value of MS Project

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

I need to retrieve Datetime value of custom fields assigned to Resource.
I can retrieve value from custom field as String value with using [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource.getfield).
This value will be formatted with [DefaultDateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.defaultdateformat) of MS Project.
Thus, the date will be represented like this(example):

> "Tue 11/21/23 7:43 AM"

Is there a way to convert String to DateTime based on known [PjDateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjdateformat)?

Comment: Have you tried `DateTime.Parse()`, or `.ParseExact()`, or one of the many overloads?

Comment: @gunr2171, `DateTime.Parse` or `.ParseExact()` the both seems don't know about [PjDateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjdateformat) . Of course I can create my solution, create mapping for each item of  enum to string format and use it in ParseExact, but curios if there is more good solution

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what the PJ format is going to be? You can translate the format into what [DateTime expects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: It sounds like the question is "how to I translate a PJ date format to a .NET date format?"

Comment: @gunr2171, There is [DateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.dateformat)  to convert date to string with using [PjDateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjdateformat)  I search a way to convert String backward to DateTime with using known PjDateFormat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with an unknown default date format is to change it to what you want and then reset it back for the user. Here is are the basics in vba, translate to c# as necessary.

```
Dim CurrentDateFormat As Long

Sub SetDateFormat()
    CurrentDateFormat = Application.DefaultDateFormat
    Application.DefaultDateFormat = pjDate_mm_dd_yy_hh_mmAM
End Sub

Sub ResetDateFormat()
    Application.DefaultDateFormat = CurrentDateFormat
End Sub
```